# Explanation of errors found by fsck on ext4 filesystem

Tags: ext4, fsck

I restarted my system from the terminal using shutdown -r now (instead of the usual option in the menu), and then I ran fsck on the filesystem and got errors like:

```
Free blocks count wrong ...
Free inodes count wrong ...
Clearing orphaned inode ...
```

And it fixed them.

Were any of these errors serious? Should I be worried there might be lingering corruption in my filesystem?

Thanks!

Comment: Occasionally run `fsck`, especially after a hang/freeze/crash. Monitor for further errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not errors. They are standard info messages.

You say that `fsck` fixed them, so there's nothing to worry about. It is not necessarily because you used `shutdown -r`. It could be due to a lot of different reasons.

As long as `fsck` was successful, there's no reason to be alarmed.

Comment: Of course these ARE errors. Not horrible ones, but errors none the less.

Answer (score 2):

To properly check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`